# Additivity of Value at Risk

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, finance

I'm struggling with the following exercise:

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $X,Y$ be two real-valued random varaibles such that their corresponding cumulative distribution functions $F_X$ and $F_Y$ are continuous and strictly monotonically increasing. Further, we assume that $(X,Y)\sim(q_X^-(U),q_Y^-(U))$, where the random variable $U$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. Show that in this case
>   $$
> VaR_\lambda(X+Y)=VaR_\lambda(X)+VaR_\lambda(Y)
> $$

**My idea:** Since $F_X$ and $F_Y$ are continuous and strictly monotonically increasing, there exist continuous inverse functions $F_X^{-1}$ and $F_Y^{-1}$ of $F_X$ and $F_Y$ such that $VaR_\lambda(X)=F^{-1}_X(\lambda)$ and $VaR_\lambda(Y)=F^{-1}_Y(\lambda)$. My main problem is that I don't really know what this $(X,Y)\sim(q_X^-(U),q_Y^-(U))$ actually means (where $q_X^-(\lambda)$ is the lower $\lambda$-quantile) or how to deal with this. One thing I saw is that for a uniformly distributed $U$ on $(0,1)$, we have that $F(X)=\mathbb{P}(U\leq F(X))=\mathbb{P}(q(U)\leq x)$. I'm not sure if this is correct in this setting or helpful, but these are the only approaches I have so far.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So, readers are supposed to guess what your notation means?

Comment: If the functions $F_X, F_Y$ are continuous and strictly monotonically increasing, $q^-_X=F^{-1}_X$ and likewise for $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint on top of my comment:

$$X+Y \sim q_X^-(U) + q_Y^-(U) = (q_X^- + q_Y^-)(U) \; .$$